# Given a set of integers find two disjoint subsets $I$ and $J$ so $|I|+|J|=k$ and $\sum\limits_{i \in I}x_i = \sum\limits_{j \in J}x_j = n^2$

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

Given a set of integers $1 \le x_1,x_2\dots,x_n \le n^2$ and a number $k \le n$.
describe an algorithm that will determine if there exists two disjoned subsets $I$ and $J$ such that $|I|+|J|=k$ and $\sum\limits_{i \in I}x_i = \sum\limits_{j \in J}x_j = n^2$

this question is form exam i had . my intuition tells me its related to linear-programming or dynamic-programming but i'm not sure .(after some search online for similar questions i'm almost sure its dynamic-programming)

Comment: do you want an efficient algorithm, or the naive one?

Comment: as efficient as possible would be nice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a naive algorithm.

1. Verify that $\sum{x_i}\leq2*n²$

If yes, then

> possible_sets = [(0,0,0)] # ($\sum{x_i}$, $\sum{x_j}$, |I|+|J|)
>
> for x in {$x_k$}
>
> > for $s_i$,$s_j$,$nb$ in possible_sets
> >
> > > if $nb<k$
> > >
> > > > if $s_i+x<n²$
> > > >
> > > > > if $nb+1=k$ and $s_i+x=s_j=n²$
> > > > >
> > > > > > return True
> > > > >
> > > > > possible_sets += (s_i+x, s_j, nb+1)
> > > >
> > > > if $s_j+x<n²$
> > > >
> > > > > if $nb+1=k$ and $s_i=s_j+x=n²$
> > > > >
> > > > > > return True
> > > > >
> > > > > possible_sets += (s_i, s_j+x, nb+1)
>
> return False

This can be optimized using symmetry between I and J

Comment: thanks looks legit .... from what i heard there is way to implement it in O($n^3$) ....

Comment: I simplified it, but it's still $O(n^6)$.